# How can I get pycharm to NOT auto-insert a closing docstring?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I hate anything in any IDE that inserts anything that I haven't explicitly told it to. Accordingly, I've turned off all of the auto-complete and auto-insert I can find, but I cannot find out how to kill this for docstrings. I type `"""` and press <kbd>Space</kbd> and it puts this in, instead:

```
"""
"""
```

How can I turn this behaviour off?

Comment: I don't think you can. Per [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/documenting-source-code-in-pycharm.html): *"In languages files, PyCharm creates stubs of documentation comments on typing the opening tag and pressing Enter."* - there is no mention of an **off** option.

Comment: It's under 'insert pair quote'

Comment: It might be worth looking at the JetBrains support site to see if there are any relevant issues/bugs reported, or open one yourself.

Answer (score 7):

It's under:

```
Editor -> General -> Smart Keys
```

Uncheck `Insert pair quote`

Also uncheck `Insert documentation comment stub`

Comment: I have turned off both `insert quote pair` and `Intentions > Python > Insert documentation string stub` and the autocomplete still occurs; are you sure?

Comment: @jonrsharpe See additional switch

Comment: Oh! I'm on v4.0.5, Win 7, and I've even tried turning it off and back on again! I will leave the OP to report on whether this fixes it for them...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Did you try the `documentation comment stub` option rather than the `documentation string stub`?

Comment: Ah no, I was looking at another one (under `Intentions`, not `Smart Keys`) - turning off comment stub seems to work for me.

Comment: I have turned off both and it is still doing this.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know then. Sorry I couldn't help. As @jonrsharpe says, maybe try the support website.

Answer (score 0):

Also try:

```
Settings : Editor : General : Smart Keys
```

Uncheck:

```
Add quotes for attribute value on typing '=' and attribute completion
```

You might want to turn off this as well:

```
Auto-close tag on typing '</'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, this does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't the correct answer to the question. But as the question was not what I was looking for, you answered exactly my question. Many thanks! This auto closing of tags, which were already close when I just wanted to add the opening tag, is so idiotic.